# Print line starting from matching string?

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am going through line by line in a file.

Each line looks similar to this: `git-app-pipeline/ci/tasks/some-task/task.yml`

I have been trying to figure out how to grep/sed/awk and set a variable equal to `some_var=ci/tasks/task/task.yml`

Can anyone help me get my desired output?

Comment: can you provide some samples of lines you want to ignore? what pattern are you searching for that makes this particular line of interest? what happens if more than one line matches your pattern? (update your question with the answers/details)

Answer (score 0):

Something like with `awk` can do the work:

```
awk '{gsub("git-app-pipeline\/","some_var=",$1)}1' input_file
```